# Finding the sum of possible values

Tags: combinatorics

$14$ students have taken part in a math olympiad. Every problem in that olympuad is solved by exactly $7$ students. Furthermore, the first $13$ students have all solved $10$ problems each. If the $14$th student has solved exactly  $k$ problems, then what is the sum of the allpossible values of $k$?

I have managed the diophantine equation: 130+$k$=7$x$ where $x$ is the total number of questions in the question paper....but i have been stuck determining the sum of the values of $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Did you read what used to be the last sentence in my answer?  I have added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the 14th student - say, Robin - did very poorly, and managed to solve some minimum number, while most of the solutions were found by the other students. Then the “$7x$” of your equation would be only a little bigger than $130$.

Now suppose in contrast that Robin did very well, so the other students were only contributing the other six answers to most of the questions. What’s the biggest set of questions that they could have given six answers to? Note that they have to supply full sets of six answers - you can’t have a case where Robin gives more than one answer to a question, so “spare” answers from the others will make sets of seven without Robin’s help.

These two limits and the multiple of $7$ rule give you the possible values of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation should have $7x$ on the right.  You are counting the total number of solutions and have been told that each question is solved $7$ times.  Now you can find $k \pmod 7$.  $k$ has to be positive.  If $k$ is too large you can't have $6$ of the first $13$ students solve all the problems the last one solved, so that puts an upper limit on $k$.  For example, if $k=1000$, there must be at least $1000$ problems, so there must be at least $7000$ solutions.  But there are only $130+k=1130$ solutions, so $k$ cannot be that large.